# how to apply border color for ion-card using ngClass

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2, ng-class, angular-ng-class

i an array like below

```
this.defaultBackground=[{"applyBackground":"true"},{"applyBackground":"false"}];
```

in my html i have used ion-card

```
<div *ngFor="let details of addressArray; let idx = index" 
    [ngClass]="defaultBackground[idx].applyBackground ? 'zerocard':'oneCardData' ">
   <ion-card></ion-card>
</div>
```

here is my css code

```
.zerocard{
        .card-ios {
            margin: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
            border: 1px solid $green-color !important;
        }

        .card-md {
            margin: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
            border: 1px solid $green-color !important;
        }

                ion-col[width-80]{
            padding-left: 15px;
            font-family: $font-roboto;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: gray;
        }
        ion-col[width-20]{
            ion-icon{
                color:gray;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }
        }

        ion-card{
            width: 100%;
        }

        ion-card-header{
            padding: 0px;
        }

        ion-card-content{
            ion-row p {
                color:black;
                margin-bottom: -5px;
            }
            ion-row{

                ion-col{
                    margin-bottom: -14px;
                    margin-left: -5px;
                    margin-top: -5px;
                }
                ion-col[width-80]{
                    text-align: left;
                    padding-left: 0px;
                }
                ion-col[width-20]{
                    text-align: right;
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    .oneCardData{
        .card-ios {
            margin: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
            //border: 1px solid $green-color !important;
        }

        .card-md {
            margin: 12px 12px 12px 0px;
            //border: 1px solid $green-color!important;
        }

        ion-col[width-80]{
            padding-left: 15px;
            font-family: $font-roboto;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: gray;
        }
        ion-col[width-20]{
            ion-icon{
                color:gray;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }
        }

        ion-card{
            width: 100%;
        }

        ion-card-header{
            padding: 0px;
        }

        ion-card-content{
            ion-row p {
                color:black;
                margin-bottom: -5px;
            }
            ion-row{

                ion-col{
                    margin-bottom: -14px;
                    margin-left: -5px;
                    margin-top: -5px;
                }
                ion-col[width-80]{
                    text-align: left;
                    padding-left: 0px;
                }
                ion-col[width-20]{
                    text-align: right;
                }
            }   
        }

    }
```

i have two object from my array which is displayed in my ui in that card i have use two color based upon the 'defaultBackground' array.

the above code always applying only oneCardData css class.

So in my inspect element i am seeing only `oneCardData` css but my `zerocard` css is not applyed

**update**

updated my html part with indext of idx in to get display true or false.

Comment: Have you tried with `[ngClass]="true ? 'zerocard':'oneCardData' ">` and `[ngClass]="false ? 'zerocard':'oneCardData' ">`? If this does what you want then `defaultBackground.applyBackground` probably doesn't return what you expect.

Comment: check my updated question @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the boolean values

```ts
this.defaultBackground=[{"applyBackground": true},{"applyBackground": false}];
```

Comment: you are right, if quotes will remove work perfect and no need to put condition as i put like 'true' in loop

Answer (score 0):

It seems your html is not proper, please update your html as below:

```
<style>
    .zerocard {
        background-color:red;
        color:white;
    }
     .oneCardData {
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
    }
</style>

<div *ngFor="let item of defaultBackground">
    <div [ngClass]="item.applyBackground=='true' ? 'zerocard':'oneCardData' " style="height:50px;">
        {{item.applyBackground}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i think my answer help you, no need index variable in for loop

Comment: Your code does produce the right output, but isn't useful in the current scenario. Mohan has an `addressArray` in his question, so your solution would result in a nested loop, or you'd still have to fit in an index variable

Comment: i answered when his html not proper, i just guess what he going to do and answer and my guess 70% correct

Answer (score 0):

It is simple in CSS. If we using `box-shadow:none;` it does not show border color. If we use padding then it works.

```
ion-card{
     box-shadow: none;
     border: black;
     background-color: white;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: You used both here, box-shadow:none and padding. But either interfere with the border IMO.

Comment: The question is with ngClass